# ruby on rails record not being updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I'm using devise on my project, i want to update others profile from my admin panel, so only users with admin role can access it, since this behavior is very different to the default devise, i decided to create a separated controller, so i can manipulate users as normal records, but for some reason when i update users, the records are not updated into the database.

THESE ARE MY ROUTES

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
  root "users#index"
  post "users/:id" => "users#show"
  get "users/:id" => "users#show", as: :user
  patch "users/:id" => "users#show"
  resources :receipts
  resources :notes

  get "users/edit/:id" => "users#edit", as: :edit_user
```

THIS IS MY CONTROLLER

```
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.update(user_update_params)
    redirect_to user
end

private
    def user_update_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:username, :names, :last_names, :guardian, :phone, :identification, :role)
    end

    def user_params
        if @user.debts.nil?
            params.require(:user).permit(:debts)
        else
            params.require(:user).permit(:add_debt)
        end
    end
```

THESE IS MY VIEW

```
<% if current_user && current_user.has_role?(:admin) %>

  <div class="container form-bg">
        <div class="row main">
          <div class="panel-heading">
                   <div class="panel-title text-center">
                        <h1 class="title">Editar usuario</h1>
                      <hr />
                    </div>
                </div>
          <div class="main-login main-center">

            <%= form_for @user do |f| %>

              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :username, "Usuario" ,class: "cols-sm-2 control-label" %><br />
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :names, "Nombres" ,class: "cols-sm-2 control-label" %><br />
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <%= f.text_field :names, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :last_names, "Apellidos" ,class: "cols-sm-2 control-label" %><br />
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <%= f.text_field :last_names, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :phone, "Teléfono" ,class: "cols-sm-2 control-label" %><br />
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <%= f.text_field :phone, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :identification, "Número de identification" ,class: "cols-sm-2 control-label" %><br />
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <%= f.text_field :identification, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :guardian, "Guardian legal" ,class: "cols-sm-2 control-label" %><br />
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <%= f.text_field :guardian, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group ">
                <label>
                  <%= f.radio_button :role, "student" , :checked => true %>
                  Estudiante
                </label>
                <label>
                  <%= f.radio_button :role, "teacher" %>
                  Profesor
                </label>
              </div>



              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :password, "Contraseña" ,class: "cols-sm-2 control-label" %><br />
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
                      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
                    <% end %>
                    <%= f.password_field :password, autofocus: true, class: "form-control", autocomplete: "off" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmar contraseña" ,class: "cols-sm-2 control-label" %><br />
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autofocus: true, class: "form-control", autocomplete: "off" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group ">
                <%= f.submit "Editar", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button" %>
              </div>

            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="invisible">asdsadsadsdsadsad</p>
      </div>
<% else %>
  <h1>Acceso exclusivo para administradores</h1>
<% end %>
```

So after reading my stack trace, it indeed tries to make the patch, but then it says that the params are not permitted, which is very weird since i already did permit them on my user_update_params method.

this what appears on my trace

```
Started PATCH "/users/12" for ::1 at 2017-01-28 13:20:53 -0500
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"IdJKYYFVh8ZJJm/RPRJd7blfQw84Ct38KjE5tZ6fTuHFK8TG04MxUu2OtQv6wfLvFJll0EYYZa+ooxP19RqOAQ==", "user"=>{"username"=>"jimena", "names"=>"Jimena44", "last_names"=>"Delgado Díaz44", "phone"=>"214123244", "identification"=>"32312", "guardian"=>"3213123", "role"=>"student", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Editar", "id"=>"12"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
Unpermitted parameters: username, names, last_names, phone, identification, guardian, role, password, password_confirmation
```

So why are my files not being updated if it even redirects as it is intended on the controller?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: update doesn't throw an error regardless of whether or not the object was updated successfully.  Normally people do something like `if user.update(params)  else render edit #show errors`  You could also do `user.update!(params)` and it will throw an error immediately if the record doesn't update successfully so you know exactly why it isn't updating.

Comment: @trueinViso even with the if statement, it redirects to user, so it seems to be doing the update.

Comment: Did you try with the `!` ? Or print out the `user_update_params` to make sure they are being sent to the update method?

Comment: @trueinViso ok, so i see the problem, it is correctly making the patch request but, then it says Unpermitted parameters: username, names, last_names, phone, identification, guardian, role, password, password_confirmation, even though i am permitting them here user_update_params

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using devise I think you need to set it up like this:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters
  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:username, :names]
  end
```

Make sure the controller is inheriting from devise:

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

You can read more about it [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/) and [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), in the parts about strong parameters.